# Unable to automate Apache cordova app using appium

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to automate the **Apache cordova** app using *appium* but not able to perform the click on floating button action. 
I can launch the app, click on other tabs/buttons using *appium*. 
I tried following code

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@content-desc='closeadd']").click()
```

This code not giving me error but not clicking on "+" button also.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch the driver's context to NATIVE_APP before clicking the floating button. If that's not the case, then a workaround would be to TAP blindly on a particular point using coordinates. You can use percentage :

```
public static void tapPercentage(AppiumDriver driver, double x_percentage, double y_percentage) throws Exception {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    int xPoint = (int) (size.width * x_percentage);
    int yPoint = (int) (size.height * y_percentage);
    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
    touchAction.tap(xPoint, yPoint).perform();
}
```

Use trial and error method to find exact percentage values to click on your floating button.

Reference : [Appium Forum](http://discuss.appium.io/t/how-click-on-options-from-floating-action-button/14060/4)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I executed it into NATIVE_APP context only because I have not switch to any WEB_VIEW context before executing the above code.

Comment: Have you set the "autoWebview" capability to true? Because it causes driver to switch to WEB_VIEW context automatically.

Comment: No.I have not set "autoWebview" capability to "true".